# Get Path of all VMs through Glob

Tags: python-3.x

I have an issue when I try to run a basic function in my code pertaining to the default locations of VMs in a Windows box. These VMs are stored as a single file. 
For some reason, the loop with the directory that glob is interacting with is not finding any files.

I have to use glob at the beginning of the path and the end of the path, so that this script can be used around my department.

I have researched with os.walk() and os.listdir(); both fail because the ways that I have written it, I get the error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`.

I need a list of the VMs so that I can write a script that clones all of the VMs within that list through the vix API.

```
def getVMs():

    vmloc = glob.glob('**\\Documents\\Virtual Machines\\*.vmdk', recursive=True)

    for f in vmloc:

        print(f)
```

The problem is that it prints an null output and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I also tried to finalize the path with creating the path through os.path and created the full path of the VM folder:

```
def getVMs():
    path = os.path.join('..','C:','\\','Users',os.getlogin(),'Documents','Virtual Machines\\',)
    for vmloc in glob.glob(path +'**.vmdk', recursive=True):

        print(vmloc)
```

It still produces a null output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lied within the fact that I was having it look for .vmdk files within the directory above the actual dir that I needed.

```
    path = os.path.join('..','C:','\\','Users',os.getlogin(),'Documents','Virtual Machines\\',)
    path1 = glob.glob(path + '**\\' + '**.vmdk' , recursive=True )
    for vms in path1:
        print(vms)
```

I was able to find all of the VMDK files after that